WiFi Adapter disables as soon as connection is established while connected to ethernet domain network
I am having an issue on my laptop where the Wi-Fi connection is automatically disabled as soon as a connection is established while connected to my work ethernet LAN domain network.
If I only connect the LAN ethernet cable while Wi-Fi is enabled, all is fine and Wi-Fi stays enabled.
If I disconnect the ethernet cable and connect to our data system Wi-Fi network, all if fine and Wi-Fi stays enabled.
If I am connected to the LAN ethernet domain network and I attempt to connect to the data system Wi-Fi network, the Wi-Fi is immediately turned off and disabled. I have to open network adapter settings and re-enable the Wi-Fi adapter.
I have already looked at the settings in HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WcmSvc\Local and also settings in the group policy editor but was not able to find anything that affected this behavior. I very well may have missed something though.
Any help or advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks!
PS. My apologies if I did not format something correctly in this post. just let me know and I'll fix it.
EDIT: I am able to connect to a Wi-Fi direct printer and remain connected, it seems to be just to our data system's Wi-Fi network.
